# Download large file from FTP server in chunks

Tags: vb.net, download, ftp, large-files

I need to download a large file from an FTP server. A new file is uploaded once a week, and I need to be the first to download the file. I've made a check which checks if the file is uploaded, and if the file is there, it will start the download. Problem is this is a big file (3 gb). I can download about 10% of the file within the first few minutes, but as more and more people discover the file is uploaded, the avg download speed drops and drops, to the point where it takes about 3-4 hours to download the remaining 80-90%.

The time isn't a huge problem, but sure would be nice if i could get the download done quicker. The problem is my download never finishes, and i think its because the connection gets timed out.

Solution would be to extend the download timeout, but ideally i have another suggestion. My suggestion is to download the file in chunks: Right now I'm downloading from the beginning to the end in 1 go. It starts of with a good downloadspeed, but as more and more people begin their download, it slows all of us down. I would like to split up the download in smaller chunks and then have all the separate downloads start at the same time. I've made an illustration:
[image]

Here i have 8 starting points, which means i'll end up with 8-parts of the zip file, which i then need to recombine to one file once the download has ended. Is this even possible and how would i approach this solution? If i could do this, i would be able complete with the entire download in about 10-15 minutes and I wouldn't have to wait the extra 3-4 hours for the download to fail and then having to restart the download.

Currently i use a web client to download the ftp file, since all other approaches couldn't finish the download, because the file is larger than 2,4 gb.

```
Private wc As New WebClient()
wc.DownloadFileAsync(New Uri("ftp://user:password@ip/FOLDER/" & FILENAME), downloadPath & FILENAME)
```

Comment: I know it's slightly off-topic, but consider looking into [Torrents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torrent_file).

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title. See: [**Should questions include "tags" in their titles?**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)